# Pointwise convergence of $c$-concave envelopes as the sequence of cost functions converges pointwise

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, limsup-and-liminf, supremum-and-infimum

On Remark 1.12, page 33 of Villani's Topics in optimal transport we find the following problem. It should be easy but it's turning me mad.

Let $c:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+\cup\{+\infty\}$ be a measurable, bounded, lower semicontinuous function, then there exists $c_l$ an increasing family of bounded uniformly continuous functions converging pointwise to $c$. Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function.

Define
$$\varphi^c(y)=\inf_{x\in X}[c(x,y)-\varphi(x)],$$
and
$$\psi_l(y)=\inf_{x\in X}[c_l(x,y)-\varphi(x)].$$
Then, it is easily seen that each $\psi_l$ is uniformly continuous, but how do we prove that $\psi_l$ converges pointwise to $\varphi^c$?

Comment: I would like to point out that the assumption used by Villani is $c$ is bounded **uniformly continuous**, not just lower semi-continuous as you quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true as stated. Define
$$\varphi(x) = \begin{cases} 0 \quad &\text{ if } x=0 \\ 1 \quad &\text{ if } x\ne 0 \end{cases}$$
and $c(x,y)  = \varphi(x)$. Clearly, $\varphi^c(y)=0$ for all $y$.

Suppose that $c_l$ is a continuous function such that $c_l\le c$. Take a sequence of nonzero numbers $x_k$ converging to $0$: then 
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}(c_l(x_k,y)-\varphi(x_k)) = c_l(0,y)-1 \le  -1$$
and therefore $\psi_l(y)\le -1$ for all $y$.

---

The author needed this "exercise" to justify the measurability of $\varphi^c$... If I were in your place, I would trust the claim that it's measurable and keep on   reading.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that's the reason for why it is so difficult to prove... because it is not true.